# foreign key of two possible tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have two tables: **Student** & **User** 
the `Student` table has a primary key of INT(9)
the `User` table has a primary key of MEDIUMINT

Now please take a look at this picture

[image: Social_Network]
<sub>(source: [imgh.us](https://imgh.us/socialNetwork.png))</sub>

Now the problem is: in the `messages` table i've the **messageFrom** and **messageTo** cols, I don't know weather the sender or the receiver is a **Student** or a **User**.

I can't reference the two tables because of different primary key types, however, am trying to avoid major changes as possible.
the same issue is everywhere **reportedPosts** table, **comment** table. Everywhere.

HOW to get around this issue or a possible solutions to fix this ?

AND please feel free to **feedback** the database structure, i would like to know and learn from your advices.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Users and Students (the entities, not the tables) are both examples of *People*. There are attributes of Users that don't belong to Students and there are attributes of Students that don't belong to Users. Also, there are actions Users may take that Students cannot take and vice versa. However, there are attributes common to both (name, address, phone number, etc.) and actions both may take (send/receive messages, post comments, etc.). This strongly implies a separate table to contain the common attributes and allow the common actions.

```
create table People(
  ID       MediumInt  auto_generating primary key,
  PType    char( 1 )  not null check( PType in( 'U', 'S' )) -- User or Student
  Name  varchar( 64 ) not null,
  Address  varchar( 128 ),
  ...,     -- other common attributes
  constraint UQ_PeopleIDType unique( ID, PType ) -- create anchor for FKs
);

create table Users(
  UserID    MediumInt not null primary key,
  UType     char( 1 ) check( UType = 'U' ),
  ...,      -- attributes for Users
  constraint FK_Users_People foreign key( UserID, UType )
    references People( ID, PType )
);

create table Students(
  StudentID MediumInt not null primary key,
  SType     char( 1 ) check( SType = 'S' ),
  ...,      -- attributes for Students
  constraint FK_Students_People foreign key( StudentID, SType )
    references People( ID, PType )
);
```

Notice that if a Person is created with a type of 'S' (Student), the ID value for that Person can only be inserted into the Student table.

Now all tables that must refer to Users may FK to the Users table and those that must refer to Students may FK to the Students table. When tables can refer to either, they may FK to the People table.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign Keys do not solve all problems.  Add a suitable index instead of depending on the FK.  Then:

Plan A:  Do the equivalent of FK checks in the application code, or

Plan B:  Forgo any FK checks.